# Array value output in html input field outputs array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I had a variable that was like this

```
$wert=$_GET['value']; 
echo "<td><input name=\"info\" value=\"${'info' . $wert}\"> </td>";
```

For example : if the value of $wert is 1, it would look like this:

```
echo "<td><input name=\"info\" value=\"$info1\"> </td>";
```

What I need to do now is to get $info1[2] in there and I tried as below:

```
echo "<td><input name=\"info\" value=\"${'info' . $wert}[2]\"> </td>";
```

But my input field only outputs Array[2] instead of the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$var = "info".$wert;  // info1

$var1 = $$var;  // $info1

$val = $var1[2];  // $info1[2]

echo '<td><input name="info" value="'.$val.'"> </td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `[2]` in to the bracket.

```
echo '<td><input name="info" value="'. ${'info' . $wert .'[2]' } .'" /></td>';
```

Be careful when you use complex string. Every time use simple string with simple quote.